# Random() happening only once

Tags: processing

I have this for() loop where I am randomizing the selection of slices of a picture, to display 16 slices of an image in a random order.

I'm picking those slices from an array and I have a variable that picks up what slice is going to be selected in the array.

The problem being that I'd think that the random function would be triggered for every frame, but it's triggered only once.

Here's the code :

```
void setup() {

    size(720,720);

    slices = new PImage[16];

        slices[0] = loadImage("1.png");
        slices[1] = loadImage("2.png");
        slices[2] = loadImage("3.png");
        slices[3] = loadImage("4.png");
        slices[4] = loadImage("5.png");
        slices[5] = loadImage("6.png");
        slices[6] = loadImage("7.png");
        slices[7] = loadImage("8.png");
        slices[8] = loadImage("9.png");
        slices[9] = loadImage("10.png");
        slices[10] = loadImage("11.png");
        slices[11] = loadImage("12.png");
        slices[12] = loadImage("13.png");
        slices[13] = loadImage("14.png");
        slices[14] = loadImage("15.png");
        slices[15] = loadImage("16.png");
        
        frameRate(1);


    
}

void draw() {

        

        for (int a = 0; a < 16; a++){

        int rand = int(random(slices.length));
        
        image(slices[rand],x,y,size,size);
         x += size;

         if (a % 4 == 3){
            y += size;
            x = 0;
            }
            
        }
```

It's dispalying the randomized slices only once and then I end up with a fix image. What I'd like to have is random slices appearing at every frame.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: which lang are you using? and where random() id declared? is it a library func?

Comment: I'm using processing. The random() function is declared inside the for() loop, inside the draw void.
It's assigning a random integer value to the variable "rand", between, 0 and the length of my array.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because you've forgot to clear the screen (e.g. calling `background()`) (meaning once you've drawn an image it will stay rendered) ?

You could also make use of the for loop in setup to avoid [repeating yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
int numSlices = 16;
PImage[] slices = new PImage[numSlices];
float x, y;
float size = 180;

void setup() {

  size(720, 720);

  
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numSlices; i++){
    slices[i] = loadImage((i+1) + ".png");
  }
  
  frameRate(1);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  
  for (int a = 0; a < numSlices; a++) {

    int rand = int(random(numSlices));

    image(slices[rand], x, y, size, size);
    x += size;

    if (a % 4 == 3) {
      y += size;
      x = 0;
    }
  }
  y = 0;
}
```

Additionally you could easily format your code (via `CMD+T` on OSX or `Ctrl+T` on Windows/Linux)

**Update** Kamakura (+1) correctly pointing out y not being reset to 0.

As a distraction I though't point you to [`IntList`'s `shuffle()`](https://processing.org/reference/IntList_shuffle_.html) method:

```
int numSlices = 16;
PImage[] slices = new PImage[numSlices];
float x, y;
float size = 180;

IntList indices = new IntList();

void setup() {

  size(720, 720);


  for(int i = 0 ; i < numSlices; i++){
    slices[i] = loadImage((i+1) + ".png");
    indices.append(i);
  }

  frameRate(1);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  // shuffle list
  indices.shuffle();
  // reset y
  y = 0;
  
  for (int a = 0; a < numSlices; a++) {

    int rand = indices.get(a);

    image(slices[rand], x, y, size, size);
    x += size;

    if (a % 4 == 3) {
      y += size;
      x = 0;
    }
  }
  
}
```

Extra reason to play with it, other than a learning experience is that fact that it will be unlikely to get the same random index repeated.

Regarding splicing/shuffling, here's a modified version of the [Load and Display example](https://processing.org/examples/loaddisplayimage.html):

```
/**
 * Load and Display 
 * 
 * Images can be loaded and displayed to the screen at their actual size
 * or any other size. 
 */

PImage img;  // Declare variable "a" of type PImage
// shuffled image
PImage imgShuffled;
// list of indices to shuffle
IntList shuffleIndices = new IntList();
// configure image slicing rows/columns
int rows = 4;
int cols = 4;
// total sections
int numSections = rows * cols;
// image section dimensions
int sectionWidth;
int sectionHeight;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  frameRate(1);
  // The image file must be in the data folder of the current sketch 
  // to load successfully
  img = loadImage("https://processing.org/examples/moonwalk.jpg");  // Load the image into the program
  // calculate section dimensions
  sectionWidth  = img.width / cols;
  sectionHeight = img.height / rows;
  // allocate a separate image to copy shuffled pixels into
  imgShuffled = createImage(img.width, img.height, RGB);
  // populate image section indices
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numSections; i++){
    shuffleIndices.append(i);
  }
}

void shuffleImage(){
  // shuffle the list
  shuffleIndices.shuffle();
  // Ta-da!
  println(shuffleIndices);
  // loop through each section
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numSections; i++){
    // index to row, col conversion
    int srcCol = i % cols;
    int srcRow = i / cols;
    // convert to pixel coordinates to copy from
    int srcX = srcCol * sectionWidth;
    int srcY = srcRow * sectionHeight;
    // get random / shuffled index
    int index = shuffleIndices.get(i);
    // same row, col, to pixel conversion to copy to
    int dstCol = index % cols;
    int dstRow = index / cols;
    int dstX = dstCol * sectionWidth;
    int dstY = dstRow * sectionHeight;
    // copy from original image to shuffled pixel coordinates
    imgShuffled.copy(img,srcX,srcY,sectionWidth,sectionHeight,dstX,dstY,sectionWidth,sectionHeight);
  }
}

void draw() {
  shuffleImage();
  // Displays the image at its actual size at point (0,0)
  image(imgShuffled, 0, 0);
}
```

[image: Moonwalk image shuffled as a 4x4 grid]

Comment: If I use the for() loop in setup, it's going to run only once.
What I want is for it to run in a loop, as it's supposed too in draw.

If I call backround () in draw before the for() loop, it displays the bacground, then the for loop, then draw starts again, displays the backround, but does not display the for() loop again.

Comment: What is the visual effect you're trying to achieve ? 

Indeed, if you call background, you'll clear each frame resulting a slices appearing and disappearing pseudo-randomly (the for loop in draw will run again btw, wether it renders what you expect is a different matter)

Comment: just to avoid confusion, what I meant by using a for loop in `setup()` is to load the images with, which is a slightly different usage from the for loop used in `draw()` to render images

Comment: I wanted to use a loop in setup() but I forgot how to name files incrementally to load them.
Well each slice is a 16th piece of an image. What I want is to shuffle these pieces (interchange their location) at every frame. So I want that for() loop to run every frame, and the random() to happen at every frame as well, because it's the random() function that's deciding in which order the pieces are going to be placed (from an array). The problem is that even if it's in draw it's running only one time. It's not shuffling at every frame. It happens once and then I get a fix image.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems in your code.
First, you may not want to choose a random index.

This is because the same image could be chosen twice.
Instead, you could shuffle the array before drawing the images, like this:

```
for (int i = slices.length; i > 1; i--) {
  //choose a random index for the i-th element to be swapped with
  int j = (int)random(i);

  //swap them
  PImage temp = slices[j];
  slices[j] = slices[i-1];
  slices[i-1] = temp;
}
```

Second, the index is chosen on every frame, and the images are drawn, too, but you can't see it, because your code never resets y back to 0, meaning that they are below the screen.

You can fix this by adding

```
y = 0;
```

to the top or bottom of your draw().